# Как анимировать смену Background'a Grid'a?

Tags: c#, анимация, wpf

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как анимировать смену `Background`'a `Grid`'a (в качестве фона - картинки) и заодно покидайте хороших статей на тему анимации или 3D в WPF  и прочих интересных вкусностей. Большое спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простейший примерчик

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
        xmlns:ee="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/effects" 
        x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1"/>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" To="VisualStateFirstImage">
                        <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.TransitionEffect>
                            <ee:BlindsTransitionEffect/>
                        </ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.TransitionEffect>
                    </VisualTransition>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:1" To="VisualStateSecondImage">
                        <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.TransitionEffect>
                            <ee:RippleTransitionEffect/>
                        </ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager.TransitionEffect>
                    </VisualTransition>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateFirstImage">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image2">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateSecondImage">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image1">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image2">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
            <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
        </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
        <Button Content="VisualStateFirstImage" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,35,0,0" x:Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Button Content="VisualStateSecondImage" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,8,0,0" x:Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="143" Click="button2_Click" />
        <Image x:Name="image1" Margin="149,74,8,8" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/BPS_background.png"/>
        <Image x:Name="image2" Margin="48,74,109,8" Opacity="0" Source="meditationdifferences.jpg"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>

private void button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.Content as FrameworkElement, "VisualStateFirstImage", true);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.Content as FrameworkElement, "VisualStateSecondImage", true);
}
```

СООТВЕТСТВЕННО нужны 2 дополнительные стандартные библиотеки Microsoft.Expression.Effects, Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.